# Node.js can't create Blobs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, audio

I am working with node.js and I streamed my Audio to my node.js server.
Now I noticed during the process of building the audio blob:

```
var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: 'audio/wav' });
```

That I get a ReferenceError at new Blob.
It seems that Blob is not supported.
How can I create a blob which I would like to save with node.js fs module?

Comment: What is Blob? Where does it come from?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

Comment: All common browser support it https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/Blob

Comment: Yeah, but a blob isn't a native Node.js type.. You know, Number, String, Boolean, Object, Array, etc. Why don't you create an object prototype or a module for NPM? Did you check NPM for anything like what you need?

Comment: I found a Blobbuilder module but it is outdated and not working.Thats why I am asking if there is a way to create a Blob inside node.js. I haven´t built a wav file object prototype yet.

Comment: Try [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). `Blob` isn't available because it's defined by a [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) and Node is not a DOM implementation.

Comment: To me it seems that those who downvoted didn´t get that there is apparently no solution to this question, that´s why I am asking.

Comment: @Jonathan I will have a look on this, but is it possible to define the MIME type?

Comment: @zer02 Yes and no. You can always add a `mime` property to the `Buffer` since it's still dynamic. But, MIME types are for communicating binary data; not so much for saving to disk.

Comment: `var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
  var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
  var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
  var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
  //var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: 'audio/wav' });`

Here is the example. Your suggestion is to create a buffer and then use `fs.writeFile('test.wav', <buffer variable>, function(err){
  if (err) console.log(err);
});`
?

Answer (score 42):

Since Node.js 16, [`Blob`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/buffer.html#class-blob) can be imported:

```js
import {Blob} from 'node:buffer';

new Blob([]);
//=> Blob {size: 0, type: ''}
```

Otherwise, just use `cross-blob`:

```js
import Blob from 'cross-blob';
 
new Blob([]);
//=> Blob {size: 0, type: ''}
 
// Global patch (to support external modules like is-blob).
globalThis.Blob = Blob;
```

Comment: Error:Must use import to load ES Modules

Comment: `cross-blob` now uses ESM - updated the answer

Comment: Blob is the default export of cross-blob, its just `import Blob from 'cross-blob'`

Comment: isn't **cross-blob** just using **fetch-blob**?

Comment: Yes, it is most useful for cross-platform situations where you don't know whether you are running in Node.js or the browser.

Comment: But how to import in express server.js which is not a module so I cant import Blob

Answer (score 11):

> ###### *Note: This answer only applies if you want to follow the Richie Bendall's answer.*

### Short answer:

**Avoid importing `Blob` from `'node:buffer'`**.

Instead, prefer importing it like this (as explained in the [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_blob). (implementation example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_blob_objects_and_messagechannel))):

```js
import { Blob } from 'buffer';
```

### Long answer:

The Richie Bendall's answer helped me a lot. But it seems that importing `Blob` from `node:buffer` breaks the Jest unit tests, throwing this error:

```sh
 FAIL  dist/tests/unit/users/getOneById.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node:buffer'

      2 | import config from '../config/config';
      3 | import { getFileExt, getFileName, removeFile } from './file';
    > 4 | import { Blob } from 'node:buffer';
        | ^
      5 |
      6 | class PdfHelpers {
      7 |

      at Runtime.readFile (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:2118:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/helpers/pdf.ts:4:1)
```

Instead of trying to mock the `node:buffer` import with some weird/tricky code, I took a look at the NodeJS documentation examples. So it demonstrates that `Blob` can be imported from `'buffer'`

```js
import { Blob } from 'buffer';

// ...

// Only the import is changing, don't change your existing implementation
const blob = new Blob([buf], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```

And all Jest errors have been gone away!

Comment: Importing with the `node:` protocol appears to have been fixed in Jest 27.1.0 which was released only 3 days before this answer was posted. https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v27.1.0

Comment: Can you help fix module '"buffer"' has no exported member 'Blob'.ts(2305)

Comment: @YTG I would say it's due to the Node version you're using, but you have a topic on this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70868796/2724204 which suggests to set your package.json dependency for `@types/node` to `"@types/node": "^16.0.0"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try use `Readable.from(value.buffer)` from "stream" node api.

It solved to me on FormData append file to send.

Answer (score -2):

Another solution to consider is to use a **Base64 String** to transfer data from the Server to the client.

I am working on a Node.js project where I receive audio data in the form of an ArrayBuffer, and I want to send and play that data in the browser. Most of my struggles came from trying to send the ArrayBuffer to the client or trying to convert the ArrayBuffer and send a Buffer.

What ended up being a simple solution for me was to

1. Convert the ArrayBuffer to a Base64 encoded String on the Server
2. Return/Send the Base64 String to the client from the server
3. Create an Audio element/object on the client side and play the sound

I used [base64-arraybuffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer) to perform the ArrayBuffer > Base64 String conversion (though, it may be simple to do this without a package).

I used tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762763/play-wav-sound-file-encoded-in-base64-with-javascript) to create the audio element on the client side.

*I haven't done much in the way of testing limits - so I don't know how this might handle large audio files.