# Wav to Blob in nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, buffer, blob

I'm not sure how to create a blob from a wav file in node. Do I just use Buffer like so?...

```
var blippityBlob = new Buffer(filePathToWave);
```

Comment: Does my answer help ? If yes then please accept it otherwise ask away if anything is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in a combination of these two posts:

[Node.js can´t create Blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%C2%B4t-create-blobs)

[Convert a binary NodeJS Buffer to JavaScript ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a look at [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/)

Quoting:

> BinaryJS is a lightweight framework that utilizes websockets to send, stream, and pipe binary data bidirectionally between browser javascript and Node.js.

Server Code

```
    var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000});
    server.on('connection', function(client){
       client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
           var file = fs.createWriteStream(meta.file);
           stream.pipe(file);
  }); 
});
```

Client Code

```
    var client = BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
    client.on('open', function(stream){
       var stream = client.createStream({file: 'hello.txt'});
       stream.write('Hello');
       stream.write('World!');
       stream.end();
});
```