# How to create a blob in node (server side) from a stream, a file or a base64 string?

Tags: node.js, server, blob

I am trying to create a blob from a pdf I am creating from pdfmake so that I can send it to a remote api that only handles blobs.

This is how I get my PDF file:

```
var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' };
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./pdfs/test.pdf'));   
pdfDoc.end();
```

The above lines of code do produce a readable pdf.

Now how can I get a blob from there? I have tried many options (creating the blob from the stream with the blob-stream module, creating from the file with fs, creating it from a base64 string with b64toBlob) but all of them require at some point to use the constructor Blob for which I always get an error even if I require the module blob:

```
TypeError: Blob is not a constructor
```

After some research I found that it seems that the Blob constructor is only supported client-side.

All the npm packages that I have found and which seem to deal with this issue seem to only work client-side: blob-stream, blob, blob-util, b64toBlob, etc.

So, how can I create a blob server-side on Node?

I don't understand why almost nobody also needs to create a blob server-side? The only thread I could find on the subject is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%C2%B4t-create-blobs).

According to that thread, apparently:

> The Solution to this problem is to create a function which can convert between Array Buffers and Node Buffers. :)

Unfortunately this does not help me much as I clearly seem to lack some important knowledge here to be able to comprehend this.

Comment: In general: Blob is an abstract concept describing a binary object, a local wrapper if you will. You can't really send a "blob" as it's basically just a binary/byte stream when hitting the net (which is why you don't really need Blob on the server). Just send the data as a binary stream from server - the client should be able to receive (via XMLHttpRequest or fetch) either as ArrayBuffer or convert the latter to Blob there.

Comment: not a constructor but yet the source says it should work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob

Answer (score -1):

use `node-blob` npm package

```
const Blob = require('node-blob');

let myBlob = new Blob(["something"], { type: 'text/plain' });
```

Comment: It gives this error, 
error: TypeError: node_blob_1.Blob is not a constructor