# Node.js cant import File instance from local folder

Tags: node.js, file, instance, fs, instance-variables

I have a problem with importing any file as a file instance from local folder.
Can you help me please?
I can't find anything in 'fs' or 'path', maby because I don't know what to see
I want to get File and pass it to my JS applicatin as a File instance.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve and how you tried it. What do you mean by "file instance"? This terminology is not used in Node.

Comment: Please post your code. it is not possible to understand based on the info provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using a path relative to your script and the `__dirname` directive.

```
fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/myfile.txt')
```

You may also wish to lose the `/` using `path` to make your code more portable.

```
const path = require('path')
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'myfile.txt')
```

In regards to format, the result will be Buffer. If you want a string,

```
fs.readFileSync(filename,'UTF-8')
```

If you want a blob, see stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349

Comment: Thank you but when I will send this to my js application how can I retrieve File instance from this?

Comment: Will this be a Buffer and I can just do tike this:
`const file = new Blob(
          [response],
          {type: some.mimeType}
          );`

Comment: It will be buffer.  If you want string, `fs.readFileSync(filename,'UTF-8')`.  If you want blob, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%C2%B4t-create-blobs