# Why JSZip can't create blob file?

Tags: node.js, jszip

I was trying JSZip on NodeJS to create some ZIP file but i'm facing an issue.

I'm using the code proposed by JSZip :

```js
var JSZip = require('JSZip')
var zip = new JSZip()
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n")
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
    //do things here
});
```

Currently the code throw an error on *generateAsync*

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: blob is not supported by this platform

Did something need to be install or the data I set in *zip.file* should be in a certain format ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js can´t create Blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%c2%b4t-create-blobs)

Comment: This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%c2%b4t-create-blobs) does not seems to be useful in my case because I'm not trying to create a Blob but trying to create a ZIP from files. If you can precise how it can help me :) Thanks

Comment: There is a [github issue](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/310) on the exact same problem. It has been wrongfully closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSZip throws this error at `jszip/lib/utils.js:352:15` because of the value of `support.blob`, defined by at [`jszip/lib/support.js`](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/master/lib/support.js) (lines 11 to 32). I don't know for your machine, but while trying to run this script in NodeJS, I've debugged it to the conclusion that JSZip detects blobs to be not supported because `self` is not defined, so [line 23](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/blob/4cbbb6450e204be6f5d494850624cbb823864b83/lib/support.js#L23) throws an error and `support.blob` is set to false.

JSZip seems to support the Node Buffer type on Node though - the following doesn't throw any errors on my machine:

```js
// JSZip v3.2.1
// NodeJS v8.10.0
// Ubuntu 18.04
const JSZip = require('jszip');

const zip = new JSZip();
zip.file('hello.txt', 'Hello world\n');
zip
    .generateAsync({type: 'nodebuffer'}) // blob -> nodebuffer
    .then(console.log);
```

Comment: `nodebuffer` YES!!