# Typescript Error: Blob is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, blob

I am stuck in a problem since last few days. What I need to do is to fetch a existing PDF file from an AWS S3 bucket and sent it back as a Blob object. This Blob object will be consumed by a mobile app for downloading the PDF. Unfortunately, I am getting the error, {"statusCode":400,"body":"**Blob is not a constructor**"}. I am writing the back end in **Typescript**.

```
const params = {
        Bucket: downloadFileConfig.s3DownloadFileBucket,
        Key: fileLocation,
      };

const bucketData = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

const blob = new Blob([bucketData.Body], {type : 'application/pdf'});

return blob;
```

I am able to successfully fetch the PDF file from the S3 bucket.

Comment: What runtime environment is this running in? Presumably server-side NodeJS, but what version? What other frameworks are you using? Is `Blob` redefined anywhere by mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js can´t create Blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653349/node-js-can%c2%b4t-create-blobs)

Comment: Nodejs does not have a Blob object.  It has a Buffer object or you can get a third party module on NPM that implements a Blob.

Comment: I am using NodeJs12.x and Typescript 3.8.3
Thanks for pointing to the similar question. I tried that earlier but didn't work either. No Blob is not redefined anywhere else.