# How to upload text file on Google drive?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-drive-api

How can I upload text file on Google drive using CloudFunctions?

File has been created on local folder but not sure how can I pass this in metadata body.

*I have followed below approach:*

**Step 1: Write file**

```
// Write file
fs.writeFileSync("sample.txt", "Hello content!");
```

**Step 2: Prepare metadata**

```
    const metadata = {
      name: "sample.txt",
      parents: [parentFolder],
      mimeType: "text/plain",
      uploadType: "media",
    };
```

**Step 3: Call Google drive API to upload file**

```
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: metadata,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        response.status(200).send(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        response.status(500).send(err.message);
      });
```

So whole function code is:

```
exports.onCreateFile = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // <-- Some validation -->
    const parentFolder = request.query.parentFolder;
    if (!parentFolder) {
      response.status(400).send("Parent folder not found");
      return;
    }

    // Write file
    fs.writeFileSync("vault.txt", "Hello content!");

    const metadata = {
      name: "vault.txt",
      parents: [parentFolder],
      mimeType: "text/plain",
      uploadType: "media",
    };

    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: metadata,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res.data);
        response.status(200).send(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // console.log(err);
        response.status(500).send(err.message);
      });
});
```

Basically Mobile app will call CloudFunction by passing accessToken and parentFolderId and cloudFunction will upload file after some business logic.

Comment: And where's the Cloud Functions?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have updated description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass the file as metadata. Instead you can pass it as form data like this:

```
    const metadata = { name: "sample.txt", mimeType: "text/plain", parents: ["root"] };
    const fileContent = "Hello content!";
    const fileBlob = new Blob([fileContent], {type: "text/plain"});
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("metadata", JSON.stringify(metadata), { type: "application/json" }));
    form.append("file", fileBlob);
    fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }),
      body: form,
    });
```

Comment: It returns 400 and now trying multipart upload but no luck.

`const form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", "Some dummy text");

axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form.getBoundary()} `,
      },
      data: form,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        response.status(200).send(res.data);
      })
`

Comment: You didn't append the metadata to the form. Try to stay as close to the sample code I posted as you can. Because the code works.

Comment: It is working but with two issues in my case and maybe you can help:
1: Don't have Blob in Node and I'm writing file with `fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/vault.txt", "Hello Temp content!");`. Appending metadata throws `ReferenceError: Blob is not defined`
2: Uploaded "Untitled" text file has 
`----------------------------866368930733703415619015
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="vault.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello Temp content!
----------------------------866368930733703415619015--`

Comment: I updated my answer. See if it is working. Unfortunately I can not test it. If it doesn't work, let me know. You can also try with `blob`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58896208/7821823

Comment: Thanks. I am glad that it is resolved and I have updated my questions with update. [link](https://mryqu.github.io/post/upload_file_to_google_drive_using_postman_and_curl/) helped to fix this issue.
Headers should be 
`{
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": `multipart/related; boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`,
      }`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it got resolved using the following approach:

```
fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/sample.txt", "Hello Temp content!");

    const metadata = {
      name: "sample.txt",
      mimeType: "text/plain",
      parents: [parentFolder],
    };

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("metadata", JSON.stringify(metadata), {
      contentType: "application/json",
    });
    formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream("/tmp/sample.txt"));

    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": `multipart/related; boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`,
      },
      data: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        response.status(200).send(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        response.status(500).send(err);
      });
```

This [Link](https://mryqu.github.io/post/upload_file_to_google_drive_using_postman_and_curl/) helped to resolve this issue.

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>